# One tap GPS toggle on Nexus 4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, gps, home-screen-shortcuts

Is there a way in Android 4.4 to activate (on/off) the GPS in only one tap on Nexus 4?

Now I use a shortcut to arrive at the GPS menu (first tap/first picture)

[image: first picture]

then click on/off (second tap/second picture)

[image: second picture]

then accept Google position option (third tap/third picture)

[image: third picture]

Is there a way to start/stop GPS in a shorter way?

Comment: @DanHulme the question is edited with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open the settings shortcut menu (two-finger swipe from the top of the screen) then long-press the "Location" setting. That's only two actions.

[image: Settings shortcut menu]

Answer (score 3):

The Android **Power Control** widget has been part of the base Android setup since version 2.1.

While the icons can vary by OS version and manufacturer, by and large it has five buttons that give you quick access to enable/disable WiFi, Bluetooth, GPS, and Sync, and also gives quick access to the screen brightness settings.

[image: My Power Control widget from Android 4.4.4]

If that's not to your taste, there are plenty of other widgets in the Play Store that add more—or fewer—buttons

Comment: After tap on GPS icon I have to tap on/off then accept Google conditions on position. So I have to tap three times with this one

Comment: Not on my phone, so take that as you will. As I mentioned, there are dozens of apps/widgets in the Play Store.

Comment: @AI E. I have updated the question with some screenshots and more details (I use Nexus4)